# How can I fetch one order from database instead of all?

Tags: php

1. I have two hyperlinks of order delivered to the customer.
2. when a customer click on first link then it should display charges and Order history.
3. My code is displaying charges correctly but its fetching all the orders. But it should display only one order that is associated with the charges.
4. Here is my billingHistory.php file
       ';

   ```
    include 'systemMenu.php';
   echo '<h4>All Charges</h4>';

        $user = unserialize($_SESSION['user']); 
     $query = "SELECT * FROM billingItems WHERE  userID='".$user->userID. " '  GROUP BY deliveryTimestamp DESC"; 
                    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                     echo '<p>';

                       echo '<a href="billingHistory1.php?deliveryTimestamp=' .$row["deliveryTimestamp"]. '">'.
                       ' Order Delivered on' . '</a>' .$row['deliveryTimestamp']  ;

                               }
                         echo '</div></body></html>';

                        $_SESSION['user'] = serialize($user);
                        include 'footer.html';
                           ?>
   ```

Here is my billingHistory1.php

```
    <?php
     include 'preCode.php';
     include 'header.php';
     echo '<body><div class="standardLayout">';
     include 'systemMenu.php';
      echo '<h2>All Charges</h2>';

      $user = unserialize($_SESSION['user']);


       $query = "SELECT * FROM billingItems WHERE userID='" .$user->userID. "'  AND  DELIVERYTIMESTAMP='" .$_REQUEST["deliveryTimestamp"]. "' ORDER BY deliveryTimestamp DESC"; 

        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         echo '<p>';
         echo '<p>'.   $row['type'] . '<br>' . 
            'Cost: $' . $row['amount'] . '<br>' .  '</p>' ;
                  }

         echo '<h2>Order History</h2>';

        $query1 = "SELECT * from Orders WHERE userID = '" . $user->userID . "' AND delivered = '1' GROUP BY ID DESC"; 
        $result1 = mysqli_query($db, $query1);

         while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
         echo '<p>';
         echo $row1["produce"] . ',' . $row1["meat"] . ',' .   $row1["bakeryBread"] . ',' . $row1["frozen"] . ',' . $row1["dairy"] . ',
           ' . $row1["snacks"] . ',' . $row1["cannedFood"] . '</p>' ;

        }

       echo '</div></body></html>';

       $_SESSION['user'] = serialize($user);
      include 'footer.html';
       ?>
```

Here is my first Output:(Order Delivered On is a hyperlink)

```
        All Charges
        Order Delivered on2015-05-16 14:48:17
        Order Delivered on2015-05-16 14:46:21
```

Here is my second output: (when a customer click on Order Delivered On(hyperlink) then it should display all the charges and only one order history that is associated with the charges, instead of showing all order histories.

```
          All Charges
           Grocery Cost
           Cost: $2.49
           Shopping & Delivery 
           Cost: $0.00

           Order History
           1 Chilli,fish,bread,ice,milk, ,
           2 Tomatoes,,,,, ,
```

Comment: use `LIMIT` Function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a LIMIT like this:

```
SELECT * FROM billingItems WHERE  userID='".$user->userID. " '  GROUP BY deliveryTimestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

...or extend your WHERE clause to be more restrictive.

Comment: if i add LIMIT 1 then its showing me  only one delivered order. But i don't want to make any changes in my first output. I want to make changes in my second output. In second output, instead of showing two order histories, it should display only one that is linked with the billing history.

Comment: If that is the incorrect record, try `SELECT * FROM billingItems WHERE  userID='".$user->userID. " '  GROUP BY deliveryTimestamp ASC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Why are you using a timestamp value as a Group By field? Is there not an "OrderID" or something unique to that order that you can use in your WHERE clause? The link should be something like billingHistory1.php?deliveryOrderID=randomordernumber - What if you have multiple orders that just happen to have the same delivery timestamp? Bad design imo.

Comment: I tried both DESC and ASC  but its not solving my issue.. If you see my first output, then there are two hyperlinks. If a person click on first link then it should display billing history and order history that  is linked with the id. But my second output is showing order history of both the hyperlink. I want to display only that order history which is linked with particular billing history.

Comment: Then it shouldn't be  `userID='".$user->userID. " '`. It should be `orderID='".$orders->orderID. " '` (I guessed as to the real names.)

Comment: No. Still struggling with the issue.

Comment: It sounds like a malformed query more than all this PHP and everything else. It may be good to post a new question focused on the problems with the query results. Post your query. Post the results you are getting. And then tell us what results you would expect to see.